# How to filter map of list objects from list of objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I want Map object out of list of objects with matched and unmatched items. In below List 2 objects with same name and joining date of one object equals termination date of other object and remaining item is itself. using java 8 Streams , i want Map with 2 different lists.

In below List 2 objects names are  equal and also joining date of 1 object equals to
termination date of other object.

After using streams i want a result with Map of List, One list object contains 2 matched items and other list contains only single item.

```
`public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Emp a= new Emp();
        a.setId("1");
        a.setName("hi");
        a.setJoinDate("20220201");

        Emp b= new Emp();
        b.setId("2");
        b.setName("hi");
        b.setTerminationDate("20220201");

        Emp c= new Emp();
        c.setId("3");
        c.setName("hello");
        c.setJoinDate("20220201");
        List<Emp> empList = Arrays.asList(a,b,c);

    

    }`
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow your code. You construct two lists, where the second is a shallow copy of the first. Then you check to see if they have the same elements. The second was constructed from the first, so they'll always have the same elements.

Comment: second list  was created for comparison purpose ,Comparing first list object attribute with second list object attribute  , is there anyway you can achieve same without creating second list ? if you run the code it will give 2 elements with name.

Comment: Comparison to *what* though? Right now, you're just checking whether every element in the list is the same, with an extra list thrown in to add complexity. I don't understand what you want to do. Can you explain the goal of this function, in plain English?

Comment: My goal is to get Map object out of list of objects with matched and unmatched items. in above list 2 objects with same name and remainingitem is itself. using java 8 Streams , i want Map with 2 different lists.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Please let me know if you still don't understand

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you wrote:

```
My goal is to get Map object out of list of objects with matched and unmatched items.
```

The following code demonstrates how to do this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupingBy {

    record Employee(String id, String name) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> list = List.of(new Employee("1", "Dumisani"), new Employee("2", "Thandiwe"), new Employee("3", "Thandiwe"));

        Map<String, List<Employee>> result = 
            list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::name));
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Note that I used `record` instead of `class` to make the demo more succinct. Also, I rename "Emp" to "Employee" -- there's no reason to skimp on descriptive names.

The result is a grouping by Employee.name. You can see that each entry's value is a list of employees whose name matches the key:

```
{Dumisani=[Employee[id=1, name=Dumisani]], 
 Thandiwe=[Employee[id=2, name=Thandiwe], Employee[id=3, name=Thandiwe]]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , But it wont work if i wanted to compare equality condition ,suppose if i want to compare Employee1 joining date equals to Employee 2 termination date.

Comment: @CRK just a tip that adding new arbitrary requirements to the problem you are trying to solve that were never mentioned in the original question is not good form. Please learn to be as clear as possible about your problem in your questions.

Comment: @pfurbacher sorry this my first question in stackoverflow and also new to java Streams, I didn't  think this scenario before.One more thing i have verified groupingBy and it always takes 2 arguments but your answer having only 1 argument.

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy` has 6 (at this writing) variants: the single parameter one is `public static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Map<K, List<T>>> groupingBy(Function<? super T, ? extends K> classifier)`. But now that you have redefined your requirement to compare two different properties, my solution doesn't apply. If you want to have two lists, one where there's a match, the other where there isn't, consider using `Collectors.partioningBy()`. I'll leave it to you to figure that out: I don't guarantee that it will be easy or even work.